# How do I preload image with getStaticProps in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I want to preload using getStaticProps in Next.js deploy to Vercel like this. but it does not work on production.how can I fix this?
Any help would be appreciated!

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const imageUrl = `https://res.cloudinary.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload/v777/my/image.jpg`
    await fetch(imageUrl);
    return {
        props: {
            imageUrl
        },
    };
};

type MyProps = {
    imageUrl: string;
};

const Mypage: NextPage<MyProps> = ({imageUrl}) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Image
                src={imageUrl}
                fill
                loading={"eager"}
                style={{ objectFit: 'cover'}}
                alt="my_image"
            />
        </Box>
    )
};
export default Mypage;
```